# Android YouTubePlayerView shows black screen when 2nd time video loading

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I created a custom layout for youtube player..

When First time loading it shows video - no problem here

If I close this page & again open the same page - It shows black screen

My code:

```
public class CustomYouTubeView extends LinearLayout implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private String mYouTubeVideoId;
private String TAG=CustomYouTubeView.class.getSimpleName();
private YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
private YouTubeIntializerListener youTubeIntializerListener;

public CustomYouTubeView(Context context){
    super(context);
}


public CustomYouTubeView(Activity context, String youTubeVideoId , YouTubeIntializerListener youTubeIntializerListener) {
    super(context);

    Log.d(TAG,"CustomYouTubeView :: ");
    this.youTubeIntializerListener=youTubeIntializerListener;

    mYouTubeVideoId = youTubeVideoId;
    //String apiKey = "AIzaSyCLLeT5eV5jCHZIjNME4MG6q_GEftd8crQ";
    String apiKey=context.getString(R.string.google_api_key);

        mYouTubePlayerView = new YouTubePlayerView(context);
        mYouTubePlayerView.setTag(mYouTubeVideoId);
        mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(apiKey, this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //int margin = (int) ScreenUtils.dip2pixel(10, context);
    params.leftMargin = 10;
    params.rightMargin = 10;
    params.topMargin = 10;
    params.bottomMargin = 10;
    addView(mYouTubePlayerView, params);
}
private void releasePlayer(){
mYouTubePlayerView=null;
}
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onInitializationFailure()");
    System.out.println("CustomYouTubeView onInitializationFailure");
    youTubeIntializerListener.youTubeFalied();
}


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, final boolean wasRestored) {

    Log.d(TAG,"onInitializationSuccess()");
    System.out.println("CustomYouTubeView onInitializationSuccess");
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onVideoStarted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess()");

                player.loadVideo(mYouTubeVideoId);
                youTubeIntializerListener.youTubeInitialized();


            }


            @Override
            public void onAdStarted() {
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Any one help me out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My code to play Youtube video is

```
YouTubePlayerView video = new YouTubePlayerView(this); 
video.initialize(SERVER_API_KEY, this);
addView(video, params);

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    if(!wasRestored) {
        try {
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(data.getString("videoId", "").toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and may be because of your's
`private void releasePlayer(){ mYouTubePlayerView=null; }` you are not getting the video played for second time, remove this function and try.

Comment: try without `private void releasePlayer(){ mYouTubePlayerView=null; }` and try by moving your `private YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;` within `public CustomYouTubeView(Activity context, String youTubeVideoId , YouTubeIntializerListener youTubeIntializerListener) {}` like ` YouTubePlayerView  mYouTubePlayerView = new YouTubePlayerView(context);` also check your logcat it might show you something which could solve your problem